# Bash: Call shell script but do not wait for return code

Tags: bash, job-control

Is it possible in Bash to call a shell script from another shell script but not have the original script wait for the sub-script to complete?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just fork it with a `&`. As in, `sh /path/to/script/script.sh &`

This will print messages from the subscript, but you can replace the & with `>/dev/null &` and suppress the output.

Comment: So the original script will continue on and can complete with a 0 exit code regardless of if the called script is still running, correct?  What if set -e is invoked, does it make a difference?

Comment: It doesn't. Once it's forked, it's on its own process and PID. `nohup` as mentioned by the other answer will also keep the process going through logouts and such.

Comment: right after you fork the process, you can "capture" its PID with $!. E.g.  `mypid=$!` .  I recommend then using `wait $mypid` at some point in your script to ensure that the forked process ends before ending the script.

Answer (score 1):

You should use "nohup" to make sure the process / script completes even if your user is logged out:

```
nohup /my/script.sh &
```